# How to run "jest" after run "serverless offline" in github action?

Tags: node.js, github-actions, serverless, ts-jest, serverless-offline

I wrote a serverless API and some jest tests. Here is my source code:
https://github.com/liou-jia-hao/serverless-typescript-no-webpack/tree/add-dev-skipauth

I wrote a test which rely on local server running.
Here are my test file:

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const API_BASE_URL = `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 7070}`;

describe('file', () => {
  jest.setTimeout(30000000);
  let uploadUrl: string;
  const fileId = 'testFile2xxxx';
  const fileExt = 'jpg';
  it('get put file url', async () => {
    const response1 = await axios.put(
      `${API_BASE_URL}/files/signed-url`,
      null,
      {
        params: { fileName: fileId, fileExt },
      },
    );
    expect(response1.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(response1.data).toMatch(/https:\//);
    uploadUrl = response1.data as string;
  });

  it('upload file', async () => {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/IMG20201004134009.jpg');
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const config: AxiosRequestConfig<Buffer> = {
      method: 'put',
      url: uploadUrl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      },
      data: buffer,
    };
    const response2 = await axios(config);
    expect(response2.status).toEqual(200);
  });
  let downloadUrl: string;
  it('get download file url', async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/files/signed-url`, {
      params: { fileName: fileId, fileExt },
    });
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(res.data).toMatch(/https:\//);
    downloadUrl = res.data;
  });

  it('download file', async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(downloadUrl);
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });

  it('list file', async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/files/list`);
    expect(JSON.parse(res.data).length).toEqual(1);
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });

  it('delete file', async () => {
    const res = await axios.delete(`${API_BASE_URL}/files`, {
      params: { fileId, fileExt },
    });
    expect(res.status).toEqual(204);
  });

  it('list file', async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/files/list`);
    expect(JSON.parse(res.data).length).toEqual(0);
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

Then wrote a Github workflow to run "npm run dev" and "npm run test".

```
name: Test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  local-test:
    name: local test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm i -g serverless@2.69.1
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ap-northeast-1
    - run: npm run dev
    - run: npm run test
```

When I push it to Github. It stuck in "npm run dev".
How can I run "npm run test" when "npm run dev" is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jest-dev-server and then solve it.

Comment: Can you post some example code of how you have set up jest-dev-server?

Comment: I follow the official document: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-dev-server

Comment: Or you can refer to my code,I remembered it should work: https://github.com/liou-jia-hao/serverless-typescript-no-webpack/tree/add-dev-skipauth

Comment: thank you. It is actually quite simple and by following the docs I managed to make it work too. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, the link which I post yesterday is blank. This is the correct doc link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-dev-server/v/6.0.3

Comment: Just in case someone like me who didn't know where to set the global-setup and global-tear down for the jest-dev-server. It is at your jest config.